# Cache staleness, even though I am not using a cache

Tags: django, caching, solr, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have uploaded my Django site on a development server at Digital Ocean and started serving it using apache2 and mod_wsgi. I am also using apache2 to serve static content. It's a fresh installation of Debian on the server, and have done minimal changes.

I am using Django Haystack and Solr to support full-text search. I've checked that both the database and Solr are kept up to date.

Now, if the url I use to retrieve a page contains a query string (it can be as small a `?asd`, where `asd` is not a valid param) everything comes out fine.

If however it does not contain such a query string, I get a version of the page that can be several hours (days?) old, even containing items I've deleted from the database.

The issue is resolved as soon as I restart apache2.

Doing `apache2ctl -M | grep cache` returns nothing, and `settings.py` does not reference caching either. Anyone have an idea what could be the cause of this?

Update: my view is a standard search view:

```
class SearchView(SearchView):
    form_class = ArticleSearchForm
    template_name = 'articles/index.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['ctx'] = context
        context['articles'] = map(lambda o: o.object, context['object_list'])
        return context
```

And the associated search form:

```
class ArticleSearchForm(SearchForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={ 'id': 'start_date', 'class': 'form-control' }))
    end_date = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={ 'id': 'end_date', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(ArticleSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        if not self.cleaned_data.get('q'):
            sqs = self.searchqueryset.all()

        if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(pub_date__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])

        if self.cleaned_data['end_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(pub_date__lte=self.cleaned_data['end_date']+datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        return sqs
```

But considering the page I get is inconsistent with what's in the database, I don't think my code gets called at all.

Update 2: It's weirder than this. *Sometimes* upon hitting refresh on my browser I get correct results. Hitting refresh again a couple of times I get incorrect results again. I tried wgetting the page on the server (via localhost) and I get *incorrect* results.

Comment: You need to show the code for that view.

Comment: Do you see any difference in the HTTP headers (expire, age, cache-control, etc.) between the "cached" and "correct" responses? Is there a load balancer in front of Apache?

Comment: Have you noticed a difference when you do a soft refresh (Cntrl/Cmd+R) and a hard refresh (Cntrl+F5)?